# Finding the norms of an Operator (under different norms)

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X := C([a, b])$ and $k(· , ·) \in C([a, b])\times C([a, b])$. Let
$$\alpha_1 := \sup_{ t\in [a,b]} \int_{a}^{b} |k(s, t)|ds$$
 and $$\beta_1:= \sup_{s \in [a,b]} \int_{a}^{b} |k(s, t)|dt$$
Define $$F(x)(s) := \int_{a}^{b}k(s, t)x(t)dt$$
 for $x \in  X$ and $s ∈ [a, b]$. Then show that

(i) $F$ is a bounded operator on $(X, ∥ · ∥_1)$, and $∥F∥ = \alpha_1$.

(ii) $F$ is a bounded operator on $(X, ∥ · ∥_{\infty})$, and $∥F∥ = \beta_1$.

(iii) $F$ is a bounded operator on $(X, ∥ · ∥_2)$, and $∥F∥ ≤ \sqrt{α_1β_1}$

For (iii) $$||F(x)||^2=\int_{a}^{b} \left(|\int_{a}^{b}k(s,t)x(t) dt|\right)^2 ds \le \int_{a}^{b} \left(\int_{a}^{b}|k(s,t)x(t)| dt\right)^2 ds$$
$$=\int_{a}^{b} \left(\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{|k(s,t)|} \sqrt{|k(s,t)|}|x(t)| dt\right)^2 ds$$

Applying Schwarz Inequality we have $$||F(x)||^2 \le \int_{a}^{b}\left[\left(\int_{a}^{b}|k(s,t)|dt\right)\left(\int_{a}^{b}|k(s,t)|x(t)|^2 dt\right)\right] ds \le \beta_1 \int_{a}^{b}\left( \int_{a}^{b}|k(s,t)||x(t)|^2 dt\right)ds$$
$$=\beta_1 \int_{a}^{b}\left( \int_{a}^{b}|k(s,t)|ds\right)|x(t)|^2 dt \le \beta_1 \alpha_1 ||x||_2$$

And we are done.

For (ii)
$$||F(x)||=\sup_{s \in [a,b]}|F(x)(s)|=\sup_{s \in [a,b]}|\int_{a}^{b}k(s,t)x(t)dt|\le \sup_{s \in [a,b]}\left(\int_{a}^{b}|k(s,t)x(t)|dt\right)$$
$$ \le ||x||_{\infty}\sup_{s \in [a,b]}\left(\int_{a}^{b}|k(s,t)|dt\right)=||x||_{\infty}\beta_1$$

For (i), $$||f(x)||=\int_{a}^{b}|\int_{a}^{b} k(s,t)x(t)dt|ds$$

$$\le \int_{a}^{b}\left(\int_{a}^{b} |k(s,t)x(t)|dt\right)ds$$
$$=\int_{a}^{b}\left(\int_{a}^{b} |k(s,t)|ds\right)|x(t)|dt \le \alpha_1||x||_1$$

I have problem in reaching these norms. Had they been discrete cases, for $||.||_{\infty}$ I would have chosen $sgn(x)$ and for $||.||_1$, $e_j$ would have done the job for me. In continuous cases I am unable to find the analogous versions of these.

Any hint will be very much appreciated. 
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Try analyzing a simple example first. Say, $(a,b)=(0,1)$, and $k(s,t)=s\cdot t$.